# What are your typical mail size batches and delviery times?

Tags: civimail, email, database, performance, mailserver

What are your typical mail sizes and time to complete mail job? Looking for comparisons...

We are having lots of mail delivery problems on a new highly customised install of Civi v5.27.1  (MariaDB v10.5.8). We have 196,000 contact records and are sending bulk mailings of max 1000, which are taking 4 hours to process. Sometimes the mail jobs get stuck in status 'running'.

We have seen a single bounce email, repeatedly trying to send, and keep the mail job runnning.
We have also seen the same email repeatedly delivering more than 20 times (until the mail job paused)

Mailer batch limit = 0
Mailer throttle time = 10
Mailer job size = 0
Mailer cron limit = 0

Our mail provider is 1&1.

Comparative performance on other civi instances much appreciated.

We are also looking for anyone specifically with civi mail expertise, system performance at server and database level.
Thanks

Comment: could you make that last point more explicit - 'looking for anyone' could mean; volunteer, emplyee, short term contract, long term contract. you may get better responses if you can clarify

Comment: Just as a data point, we can usually send about 6000-10000 emails per hour. Civi 5.28.4, though this has been the same for years, sending via AWS SES. The limit is on our end, not the AWS end. We have batch limit 400, 10 throttle time, 100000 job size. Have you tried another mail provider? AWS is easy to set up to test.